# Mysql OR query with a join returns an out of memory error

Tags: mysql

I have a query that tries to tell is a member had participated in any of 3 types of actions.  Each action is represented by a table that I am joining.  And then I am doing an or to see if there is a match in any of the tables.  Here is the query:

```
select problems.problem_id, problem_title from 
problems left join attempted_solutions 
             on roblems.creator_member_id = attempted_solutions.suggester_id 
left join problem_comments 
             on problems.creator_member_id = problem_comments.user_id 
left join suggested_solutions 
             on problems.creator_member_id = suggested_solutions.suggester_id 
where attempted_solutions.suggester_id = 1 
    or problem_comments.user_id = 1 or suggested_solutions.suggester_id = 1;
```

But for some reason this gives a "MySQL client ran out of memory error." if I try it command-line, and a "database connection interrupted" error if I do it from a script.

Any idea where I am going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This thread has some solutions maybe you should try them see if any of them is your problem

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?37,94800,232288#msg-232288

also, try to simplify your query then add your joins and where statements back one by one so that you can detect the exact cause of your problem